# Replace '**' with 'math.pow' in Python

Tags: python, parsing, pow

I have some mathematical functions (represented as strings) in a file:

```
1+a**(b/(3*a+1))
(1+a)**(b/(3*a+1))
...
```

How can I transform  all `**`s in my string to `math.pow`?

Edit: What I'm trying to solve is the following : 
I've a lot of this functions to evaluate, I can't spend too much time on one.

Sometimes functions look like that :

```
(3**100**100**2)
```

Python try to evaluate it, which is very long. 
I would like to have an error instead like :

```
>>> math.pow(3, math.pow(100, 100))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: math range error
```

Edit 2 : Thanx all for answering, I finally found how to do it, and your answers and comments helped me a lot. 
I just had to force float division with next line at the top of my file :

```
      from __future__ import division
```

Comment: do you wants `math.pow(1+a, (b/(3*a+1)))` ?

Comment: You are aware that there is a `**` operator in python correct?

Comment: This requires more than a simple text replacement; you'll need to create a proper parse tree of each expression and regenerate the expression after swapping out the operator with a function call.

Comment: I think OP wants to turn python code (at least parts of it) into some other language. I would recommend using an `ast` based approach, though that might be overkill for this specific problem.

Comment: Seriously though, what are you trying to do? There might be a simpler way to achieve your overall goal than to do find/replace on python code

Comment: Yes, i'm aware that `**` exists in Python. BUt I still need to switch the notation :). @ Grijesh Chauhan : yes, it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you are trying to parse strings, you may find Sympy helpful. In particular: `from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Try : `st=re.findall('\s*(.+)\*\*(.+)\s*',lines_from_file_as_string,re.MULTILINE)`
Gives individual elements x,y for pow(x,y)

Comment: Treating all numeric literals as floats would solve the problem here too

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following transformer:

```
import ast

pow_func = ast.parse("math.pow", mode="eval").body

class PowForDoubleStar(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        node.left = self.visit(node.left)
        node.right = self.visit(node.right)

        if isinstance(node.op, ast.Pow):
            node = ast.copy_location(
                       ast.Call(func=pow_func,
                                args=[node.left, node.right],
                                keywords=[]
                               ),
                       node
                   )

        return node
```

In your particular example you can execute those code parts using

```
for line in file:
    node = ast.parse(line, mode="eval")
    node = PowForDoubleStar().visit(node)
    code = compile(node, "<string>", mode="eval")
    a, b = 1, 3
    result = eval(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be trying to avoid here is long integer arithmetic, which can take an arbitrarily large amount of time to execute. The easiest way to fix this is:

```
class Floatify(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Num(self, node):
        return ast.Num(float(node.n))
```

Which when used:

```
>>> node = ast.parse("(3**100**100**2)", mode="eval")
>>> node = Floatify().visit(node)
>>> code = compile(node, "<string>", mode="eval")
>>> eval(code)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    eval(code)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```